# Check for .net framework 4.5.2 in registry in wix

Tags: wix

How can I check for .net framework 4.5.2 in registry using wix. I've tried this

```
<Property Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"/>
<Condition
  Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.5.2. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED]]>
</Condition
```

but it is not working. I am using wix v3.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally after trial and error I managed to solved the issue using

```
<Condition
  Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.5.2. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45>="#379893"]]>
</Condition>
```

The condition returns a `DWORD` which will be prefixed with a `#` sign
and the condition should be

```
<![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45>="#379893"]]>
```

The value `379893` is the `Value of the release DWORD`. More information can be found from this [Microsoft site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965(v=vs.110).aspx#detect_net)

*EDIT*: fixed typo.

Comment: Found the cause, LaunchConditions action in our kits was scheduled too early - before SetWIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a PropertyRef element that has an ID of WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED

```
<PropertyRef Id='WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED' />
```