# .NET 4.5.2 is not detected in silent mode by WiX 3.10.2

Tags: c#, .net, wix, .net-4.5.2, wix3.10

We have updated our kits to use WiX 3.10.2 and detect .NET Framework 4.5.2 using **WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED** property - this works, however not in all cases.

When installation is started in silent mode (/qb switch), WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED is not set.

On the other hand property **WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED** is set to **#379893**

I can workaround this issue similar to what was done in [Check for .net framework 4.5.2 in registry in wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717582/check-for-net-framework-4-5-2-in-registry-in-wix), but I would rather find the cause of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My bad,
LaunchConditions action in our kits was scheduled too early - before SetWIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED